# regex select everything but the word before the word given

Tags: regex

so i need to select the number 300 for example (the number is random) from the the phrase 
for example

```
read the book s3 300 free
```

how do i select everything exept 300 ?

keep in mind the word free in the end is always the same

i that is not possible it can also be split into multiple selection to remove a part each time so that in the i will have 300 left

also s3 sometimes the number is there sometimes 2 numbers like s20 sometimes that word is not on the phrase like just read the book 300 free

Comment: What regex tool/language are you using?  There may be an easier way to do what you want.

Comment: well, some details is missed. are the number is always in that location ? it's came after specific thing ?

Comment: Just clarifying, if you need to get the number, why select everything else ? Just selecting the number itself would be simpler right ?

Comment: that is true the problem is that i am using a plugin to do this and so i need to keep 'trimming that string untill only the value 300 is left

Comment: The title and first two sentences seem mutually-inconsistent. You need to explain what you want to do in a single statement that is complete and unambiguous. Don't confuse things by giving alternative statements. One possibility, for example, is, "I am given a string that ends with the word "free". If "free" is immediately preceded by one or more digits followed by a space I wish to select everything in the string that precedes those digits". That's just an example; I don't know if it's actually what you want.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks a lot for taking the time to help me out i will take this into consideration in my next questions , however the issue is already resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly a regex replacement is probably the best approach here.  Consider:

```
Find:    \b\s*\d+ (?=free$)
Replace: [ ] (single space)
```

### Demo

If you instead want to *capture* the value `300` (or whatever random number might be there, then use:

```
Find:    ^.*\b(\d+) free$
Replace: $1
```

### Demo

Comment: he said the number is random !

Comment: this is close that what i am looking for however the number 300 is always changing into other numbers and it is the value that i am trying to get from the string
so that i can delete everything and leave 300 :)

Comment: matching everything without match any digits aside together is the key then

Comment: i am trying to get a regex that does the opposite of since 300 is the value i want i need regex that selects everything exept 300 so that i delete everything with space and leave 300 , is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: you are a genius! thanks a lot, you saved me hours of research

Comment: Glad to hear that!  This is what the site is supposed to be all about `:-)`

Comment: one last thing is it also possible to get that 300 and replace it with another word + the 300 like the phrase will be instead  read the book s3 chapter 300 free

Comment: Yes; just change the replacement to whatever you want.  For now, my answer just replaces with `$1`, but you may add any text before/after this.